# Class attr and methods

Tags: python, jython

With Class attributes and methods, to reference them within the class, should we use Classname. or self.

Answer (score 0):

I think both ways work, but it is a bit wierd compared to Java.

Answer (score 0):

`self.attr` refers to the instance's attribute, and *falls back* to the class if there is no attribute of the specified name defined on the instance. Usually this is reasonable behavior. Use `self.__class__.attr` if you specifically want to get the class's attribute.

It is rare that anyone will override a method on an instance, this requiring the construction of a special "instance method" object, so `self.method()` is generally correct (even for methods declared using `@classmethod` or `@staticmethod`).

Comment: I ask the question because jython unittest library is not like the ones of JUnit or TestNG where JUnit or TestNG's static assert methods are imported and used without referencing the your test classes. In jython unittest, if you inherit unittest.Testcase, you can call assert methods without the self keyword as a param(self.assertEquals(t_date.year, year). If you use assert methods from unittest.TestCase, you have to include the self keyword as a param like unittest.TestCase.assertEquals(self, t_date.year, year). Don't you think it is wierd.